Pip not able to install getkey. Error Note: 'This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip'
I want to install the getkey module for python but whenever I try to install it using the command pip install getkey it doesn't install it and throws a big error.
What I did was that I downloaded the source code of getkey module and compiled it myself after fixing the problems in the code. but still it included something called EGGS so it is not working so greatly (a bit of minor errors in getkey). whenever I use pip now it shows a notification above that downloading getkey from pip would remove EGGS or something. Pip is working fine with other packages rn but it is not installing getkey due to the errors that are in the source code.
These are the following errors pip sends when I use the command 'pip install getkey':
example_directory>pip install getkey
Collecting getkey
  Using cached getkey-0.6.5.tar.gz (13 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "example_directory\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0zikq__\getkey_3a81333887014ff2a491586f3d858486\setup.py", line 37, in <module>
          long_description=read_description(),
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "example_directory\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0zikq__\getkey_3a81333887014ff2a491586f3d858486\setup.py", line 11, in read_description
          return fd.read()
                 ^^^^^^^^^
        File "example_directory\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 876: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

is there a way I can install getkey using pip without the EGGS thingy and yes I also tried installing older versions of getkey using pip but all of them had the same problem

https://github.com/kcsaff/getkey/issues?q=is%3Aissue+return+codecs.charmap_decode

https://github.com/kcsaff/getkey/issues/24#issuecomment-1565418975 suggests an alternative, though you should verify that it doesn't contain unwanted code or etc.

https://github.com/kcsaff/getkey/issues/22#issuecomment-1566281259 proposes a fix.

Thanks for the help everyone!
using pip install get-key I was able to download 'TheIceBergBots' get-key module without any error! Thanks
